# How to show a natural number $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that a natural number $p > 1$ has the property that for all nonzero integers $a$ and $b$, if $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$. Show that $p$ is prime.

I can't seem to figure out how to prove this. I have the proof of the converse and it uses a corollary about relative primes:

If $p \nmid q$, then $1 = sp + tq$ for $s,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $p$ is not prime, then $p=ab$ some $a,b$ with $a>1$ and $b>1$.

Comment: ... and obviously p divides ab = p, but a < p and b < p, therefore p doesn't divide a < p or b < p.